# I want my menu icon to overlap the hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have this menu icon on my site...

[image: menu-icon]

that when clicked opens this sidenav menu...

[image: sidenav]

But instead of using that cheesy 'x' to close it, I want to use the same icon to open it, so what I want to do is have it overlap the sidenav when it pops out instead of the sidenav overlapping the icon, but i just cant find out how.

```css
/* General */
body{

    background-color: #555;
    margin: 0;   
    padding: 0;

}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: selfish;
    src: url(assets/SELFISH_.TTF);
}

a {
    font-family: selfish;
}

/* Header */
#main #header {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    /*height: 105px;*/
    /*height: 15%;*/

    /*box-shadow: 10px 0px 5px black;*/
}

#main #header .header-logo{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 50%; 
    margin-left: 40%;;
    float: left;
    
}

    /*header menu icon*/
    #main #header .menu-icon div{
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 6px 0;
        
        }
    #main #header .menu-icon{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 36px;
        
        position: relative;
        
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
/* Side navigation */
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 12;
    top: 0;
   float: right;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #A42626;
}

.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 60px !important;

}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<body>


<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">x</a>
    <a href="#">Home</a>  
    <a href="#">Ballroom</a>  
    <a href="#">Restaurant</a>
        <a href="#" style="margin-left: 35px; font-size: 25px;">Menu</a>  
    <a href="#">Catering</a>   
    <a href="#">Contact</a>   
</div>
    
<div id="main"><!--Start main div_____________________________-->
    <!--Header-->
    <div id="header">
        <img class="header-logo" src="images/header-logo_png_checkered-compressed-short.png"/>
        <div class="menu-icon" onclick="openNav()">
                <div></div>
                <div></div>
                <div></div>                
        </div>

    </div>


    
    
    
</div> <!--End of main div______________________________-->

    

<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: you have to view the snippet in full screen, stackoverflow's UI element covers the menu icon and the X

Comment: The code in the snippet works, I'm able to open and close the navbar without issues, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Xposedbones i dont want to use that cheap looking 'x' to close it, i want to use the same menu icon i used to open it to close it, but no matter what i try, the sidenav always overlaps the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the menu icon out of the header so that you can layer the sidenav between the header and the icon, then just fix the icon where it currently is, and give it a higher z-index than the side-nav (at least 13). Lastly update your JS to toggle instead of just open.

```
var navOpen = false;

function toggleNav() {
  if (navOpen) {
    closeNav();
    navOpen = false;
  } else {
    openNav();
    navOpen = true;
  }
}

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pv9f2qwm/

Check out the fiddle for the full working solution.

EDIT: Alternatively, if you want the header to stay on top of the side nav you can leave the HTML as is, and just add the toggle code and add a z-index of 13 to the header, like in this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/qv12nwe8/

Answer (score 0):

There you go. https://jsfiddle.net/jwtf6fad/1/

Use the same code that is present in the header :)

```
.menu-icon div{
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 6px 0;

    }
.menu-icon{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 36px;

    position: relative;

    cursor: pointer;
}
#mySidenav .menu-icon{
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 14px;
}
```

and reuse that bit of code

```
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="closeNav()">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>                
</div>
```